# Center align using xlsxwriter (without conditional formatting)

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Using xlsxwriter, one can write a dataframe 'df' to Excel 'simple.xlsx' using code such as:

```
import pandas as pd
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

With above code, I see that the resultant Excel sheet has all cells (except header) as default left-aligned.

Question:

How can I make the Excel cell values to be center-aligned?
I did explore using conditional formatting but, with my cell values being combination of blanks, zeros, floats, strings and integers, I am wondering if there is another way.
Is there a smarter/quick way to do either/both of the following:

- Any way to write dataframe to Excel as center-aligned? Or..
- Any way to center-align the Excel sheet (for the cell range occupied by dataframe) once the dataframe has already been written to Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the below line to your code

```
df=df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'})
```

Your complete code would be

```
import pandas as pd
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df=df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'})
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Using above code, I was prompted to installed 'jinja2' library. Once I did so, the code worked, thanks! I am wondering if I need to sketch Excel sheet border around specific dataframe columns, would I be able to do something similar? Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no need to install 'jinja2' (I don't have it on my machine). Excel sheet borders are property of excel. I am not sure if there is an option to control that from Pandas.